I Have written a test class but execute method is not covering fully
//System.schedule('Daily Data Cache Refresh Job', '0 0 7 * * ?', new AttributionCacheRefreshBatch());

global class AttributionCacheRefreshBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM User where IsActive = true LIMIT 1]);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
        System.debug('Execute started BC'+BC);
        System.debug('scope'+scope);

        AttributionTuneInController.getDealData(true);
        AttributionTuneInController.getNetworks(true);
        AttributionTuneInController.getSvodNetworks(true);
        AttributionExposureController.getBrandData(true);
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        System.debug('Daily Data Cache refresh batch job completed.');
    }

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}

In the above execute method it should cover all the 4 methods in AttributionTuneInController where it is used to pass parameter to clear the cache which is store already
The execute method parameters contains BatchableContextImpl:[childJobId=7076t0000MHvYG9AQN, jobId=7076t0000MHvYG7AQN], scope(User:{Id=0052S000009wvxrQAA})

It'd help to see your test class too, but I suspect the issue is that tests can only cause async code to run one level deep (and you have two levels here, schedulable, then batch). You should primarily be calling the start/finish and both execute methods directly in your test (we can generally pass null in for batchable/schedulable/queueable context). The idea is that your tests should stress the logic that you have written, not that the scheduleable/batchable machinery works (which is a black box to us, and Salesforce's responsibility to test).

Also, general consensus is that you should avoid using the global visibility modifier unless you know you need it (e.g. for if you're making a managed package or need to make it available for a Flow or LWC to use).

I think you'll need to create a test class that properly simulates the batch and schedulable execution. This will involve scheduling the batch job and verifying that the methods in AttributionTuneInController and AttributionExposureController are called.
I have pasted the sample code based on your business class, you can take this as a reference. Try this out with your modifications might help you.
@isTest
public class AttributionCacheRefreshBatchTest {
    
    @isTest
    static void testBatchExecute() {
        // Set up test data
        User testUser = new User(
            Username = 'testuser@example.com',
            LastName = 'Test',
            Email = 'testuser@example.com',
            Alias = 'tuser',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        insert testUser;
        
        // Schedule the batch job
        Test.startTest();
        String jobId = System.schedule('Test Job', '0 0 7 * * ?', new AttributionCacheRefreshBatch());
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Verify the job execution
        CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE Id = :jobId];
        System.assertEquals('0 0 7 * * ?', ct.CronExpression);
        System.assertEquals(1, ct.TimesTriggered);
    }

    @isTest
    static void testBatchableExecute() {
        // Set up test data
        User testUser = new User(
            Username = 'testuser2@example.com',
            LastName = 'Test',
            Email = 'testuser2@example.com',
            Alias = 'tuser2',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            ProfileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id,
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
        );
        insert testUser;

        Test.startTest();

        // Create an instance of the batch class
        AttributionCacheRefreshBatch batch = new AttributionCacheRefreshBatch();

        // Execute the batch
        Database.executeBatch(batch);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}


N.B. One should never test that system.schedule works (that is SFDC's responsibility)  One should construct the schedulable and then invoke its execute method, verifying that an AsyncApexJob was created of type batchable
